# User Input Validation

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple income tax calculator and would like too add some user input validations. Currently I am experimenting with a TryParse method. I would like my program to check each input for the specific input types and if an invalid input is entered, the program will first notify the user then ask them to try again.

My current attempt successfully detects whether or not the input types are correct, but I am unsure on how I can redirect the user to retry. Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace IncomeTaxCalculator
{
    class IncomeTaxV2
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Define variables
            const double incomeTax = 0.02, deduction = 10000; // Constant values - These never change
            int children; // Amount of children
            double Taxdue, totalIncomeTax; // Decimal valued variables

            // Ask total income
            Console.Write("What is your total income: ");
            bool succeed = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out totalIncomeTax);

            // Ask amount of children
            Console.Write("How many children do you have: ");
            bool succeeded = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out children);


            // If statement to check input validation.
            if (succeed && succeeded) 
            {

                // User input validation

                // Calculate Deductions
                int childTax = children * 2000; // total amount for each child
                double total_deductions = (double)deduction + childTax; // total deductions = 10k + childtax

                // Calculate User input tax takeaway (-) the total amount of deductions (Equation above)
                double taxDueCalc = totalIncomeTax - total_deductions;

                // Find 2% of the Result for the amount of Tax due
                Taxdue = taxDueCalc * incomeTax;

                // Print result
                Console.Write("You owe a total of $" + Taxdue + " tax.");
            } else
            {
                // Notify user of error
                Console.Write("You must enter a valid number.");
                // Redirect too first set of TryParse statements

            }

            // End program
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n Hit Enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        }
}
```

Redirect must go into else statement. After researching potential methods it seems I might have too learn too use functions and pass information through parameters.

Comment: Is given code structure changeable? **After researching potential methods it seems i might have to learn to use functions and pass information through parameters.** means we do not need to follow your structure right?

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach is to use a loop, and signal the end when user entry has completed:

```
  bool entryCompleted = false;
  while (!entryCompleted)
  {
    if (succeed && succeeded)
    {
      // ..
      entryCompleted = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have been told not too use loops and investigate other options

Comment: _"I have been told not too use loops"_ is this an assignment / homework? @TomTok

Answer (score -1):

I will use the recursive function for this question.

```
public static void Main()
{
    incomeTax();
    // End program
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n Hit Enter to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public void incomeTax()
{
    // Define variables
    const double incomeTax = 0.02, deduction = 10000; // Constant values - These never change
    int children; // Amount of children
    double Taxdue, totalIncomeTax; // Decimal valued variables

    // Ask total income
    Console.Write("What is your total income: ");
    bool succeed = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out totalIncomeTax);

    // Ask amount of children
    Console.Write("How many children do you have: ");
    bool succeeded = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out children);


    // If statement to check input validation.
    if (succeed && succeeded) 
    {
        // User input validation

        // Calculate Deductions
        int childTax = children * 2000; // total amount for each child
        double total_deductions = (double)deduction + childTax; // total deductions = 10k + childtax

        // Calculate User input tax takeaway (-) the total amount of deductions (Equation above)
        double taxDueCalc = totalIncomeTax - total_deductions;

        // Find 2% of the Result for the amount of Tax due
        Taxdue = taxDueCalc * incomeTax;

        // Print result
        Console.Write("You owe a total of $" + Taxdue + " tax.");
    } else {
        // Notify user of error
        Console.Write("You must enter a valid number.");
        // Redirect too first set of TryParse statements
        incomeTax();
    }
}
```

When the input number is invalid, it will call back the same function. This happens until the program enters `if` statement.